# Perform simple operation on single column in panda dataframe without using .apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe `df`. I would like to transform the values of one of the columns `col_X` such that ;

```
if col_X_value < 0:
    col_X_value = 0
```

I can do that if I write a separate python function, then use the `apply` function.

This link describes how it can be done with .apply.
http://jonathansoma.com/lede/foundations/classes/pandas%20columns%20and%20functions/apply-a-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/

However, I do not want to write a python function for such a simple operation. How can I do this without writing a separate python function and using `apply`?

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the pandas version of `where`

```
df.col_X_value.where(df.col_X_value > 0, 0)
```

This will fill return 0 if the value is less than 0 and the value if not

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.loc` to slice the `DataFrame` and set portions accordingly. First, create a boolean Series where `df['col_X_value'] < 0` and where that is `True` set `'col_X_value'` to 0

```
df.loc[df['col_X_value'] < 0, 'col_X_value'] = 0
```

---

And in this case, you can actually use one of the pandas functions `.clip_lower` to achieve what you want.

```
df['col_X_value'] = df.col_X_value.clip_lower(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `clip`

```
df = df.clip(lower=0)
```